# Abrir PDF almacenado en directorio externo desde android studio

Tags: java, android, pdf

Mediante JSON obtengo unos PDF's que los encondeo a base 64 y los guardo en la de la siguiente forma:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/documentosConsumerTemporal/pdfConsumer_" + oNombreDocumentoMatriz + ".pdf");
                                    out.write(Base64.decode(oDatosDocumentoMatriz, Base64.DEFAULT));
                                    out.flush();
                                    out.close();
```

Y lo guarda de la siguiente forma:

```
/storage/sdcard0/documentosTemporal/pdf_SPV.pdf
```

Luego, desde otro activity quiero lanzar esos PDF's de la siguiente forma:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/documentosConsumerTemporal/pdfConsumer_SPV.pdf"), "application/pdf");
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(ActivityDatosNumeroOperacion.this, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/documentosTemporal/pdf_SPV.pdf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

pero me sale el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
La ruta de acceso al documento no es valida
```

He probado guardando en la ruta de la misma apliacación con el siguiente codigo:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(getFilesDir() + "/pdf_" + oNombreDocumentoMatriz + ".pdf");
```

Pero me da el mismo mensaje, que no encuentra.

He probado abrir el PDF directamente y si abre, pero mediante codigo no. Que puede ser?, permisos estan OK, tengo que ponerlos en una carpeta ya establecida?

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba de esta manera:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/documentosConsumerTemporal/pdfConsumer_SPV.pdf");
    Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
    target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);


    Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Abrir PDF");
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // el usuario no tiene ninguna app que pueda abrir pdfs
    }
```

o en vez de `getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()` cambia a `getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`